# Can I use the 15GB space offered free in Google Drive to host a website? If yes then how?

Tags: google-drive, hosting

I am a newbie to all this. And am currently planning as well as learning to make a dynamic site.. Can I host site on the free space offered in Google Drive?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

1. Create a new folder in Drive and share it as "Public on the web."
2. Upload your HTML, Javascript, and CSS files to this folder.
3. Open the HTML file and click **Open** in the bottom-right corner.
4. Click the "Preview" button in the toolbar.
5. Share the URL that looks like "www.googledrive.com/host/..." from the preview window and anyone can view your web page.

[image]

[[source](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970)]

Answer (score -1):

Yes (kind of) you can host a website on Google drive and it should be purely html, css & JavaScript. You can't do any server side scripting and you do not have a database. And you get a weird url.   Better option is to host your website somewhere else and if you need extra space use drive as storage point. (Here basically you are uploading content and sharing).